# Can't connect to MySQL -unable to connect to any of the specified mysql hosts vb.net

Tags: mysql, vb.net

i have created an installer for my vb project. it tried to install it to my work PC and it worked. I then installed it to a different PC. It was installed successfully but when i tried to to run it, the system was unable to connect to my database. It is giving me an error:

```
Can't connect to MySQL -unable to connect to any of the specified mysql hosts
```

I only created an installer that has the `.exe` in it and the database, nothing else.

Am I missing some requirements or additional application that is needed for a `vb.net application` with a `mysql database` to run smoothly on a different PC? what is it?

What causes the issue?

thanks in advance!

Comment: Does your code use a fixed connection string, particularly one naming 'localhost' as your server? If not, have you tried connecting to your database from this computer directly?

Comment: i have a localhost as server

Comment: localhost tells whatever machine you are running the application on that the MySQL database exists on that machine. When your application is installed on other machines, you need a different connection string that points to the machine where the server is installed on your network. The best way is to allow the user to input the server directory (because you don't know if your network will change in the future).

Comment: how could i do that?

Answer (score 0):

As we discussed in the comments above, using 'localhost' to connect to your MySQL server only works on the machine where the server is installed. To connect to your server from other machines, allow the user to enter the path to your server and save that information outside of your MySQL database so that the user doesn't have to enter it every time.

First, if you don't have a properties file already, create one by saving a .txt file in your project's bin folder. (For me, that's Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects[PROJECT NAME][PROJECT NAME]\bin\Release - the path is likely the same or similar for you.) If this is all you're storing, just type `localhost` in the txt file and save it as properties.txt. If you're still debugging, copy the file to the bin's Debug folder as well.

```
Imports System.IO

Dim filePath as String = Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().CodeBase) & "\properties.txt"
Dim serverPath as String
Using fReader As New Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.TextFieldParser(filePath)
    fReader.TextFieldType = FileIO.FieldType.Delimited
    fReader.SetDelimiters(",")
    Dim currentRow As String()
    While Not fReader.EndOfData
        Try
            currentRow = fReader.ReadFields()
            'If you have other values stored here, check that length of currentRow matches the number of properties you expect to import and import anything else you have saved here
            serverPath = currentRow(0) 'or whichever place you save it in your file
        Catch ex As Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.MalformedLineException
            'File is not formatted as expected
        End Try
    End While
End Using
```

Place the above code at an appropriate place in your project so that it executes once before you try to connect to your database. Then take your existing code to connect to your database, replace "localhost" with "serverPath" (concatenated into your SQL command, of course) within this code:

```
Dim oldPath As String = serverPath
Do
    Try
        'Your existing code with the server path passed as a variable here
        If serverPath <> oldPath Then
            'The path that worked isn't the one that was saved. Update file
            Using file As FileStream
                file.Open(filePath)
                file.Write(serverPath) 'Update to meet your needs if you have other variables stored here.
                file.Close()
            End Using
        End If
        Exit Do
    Catch ex As MySQLException
        'The path saved in your file is not working. Get a new one and try again.
        serverPath = InputBox("Please enter the directory to the database server:", "Unable To Locate Server")
        If serverPath = "" Then
            'User either clicked Cancel or left field blank
            Exit Sub 'Or whatever else you want to do when the user aborts
        End If
    End Try
Loop
```

Give that a whirl. There are other ways of reading and writing files you can look into, but this should do everything you need.

Comment: thanks.. i have an exported mysql database..and i intend to just place the database to the computer where the application will be installed..the database is built for only one PC..

Comment: i tried installing mysql connector and server to the PC in hope to fix the problem. But it showed new error "authentication to host 'localhost' for user 'root' using method 'mysql_native_password' failed with message: Unknown Database "

Comment: If each machine your application runs on needs to host it's own MySQL server, then your installer needs to install MySQL on each machine and import your existing database. I've never used a SQL database in this manner so unfortunately I can't help you there. I doubt you want to go back and rebuild your database at this late phase in your project, but since each instance of your application only requires a local instance of your database and ignores changes made to the database on other machines, it would be a lot simpler to take MySQL out of the equation and just use a standard OLE database.